# dash path between two intersections with other path

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, intersections, tikz-knots

I wish to dash the red path when it is between the intersections with the blue path. How can I do this using paths names?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red , ultra thick,name path=A] (0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,1).. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,0) ; 
\draw [ white , double=blue , ultra thick , double distance=1.6 pt, name path=B] (0,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\makeatletter 
\tikzset{recycle path/.code=\pgfsyssoftpath@invokecurrentpath#1} 
\makeatother 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \path[save path=\pathA] (0,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,0) .. 
    controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,1); 
    \begin{scope} 
    \clip[recycle path=\pathA] |- (0,1cm+1.4pt); 
    \draw [red , ultra thick,dashed] (0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,1).. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,0) ; 
    \end{scope} 
    \begin{scope} 
    \clip[recycle path=\pathA] -- (4,-0.4pt) -- (0,-0.4pt); 
    \draw [red , ultra thick] (0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,1).. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,0) ; 
    \end{scope} 
    \draw [white , double=blue , ultra thick , double distance=1.6 pt,use path=\pathA]; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>This answer is community wiki because the code is not mine.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You can find intersections and clip inside relavant rectangle to draw the dashed curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,name path=A,save path=\pathA]  
(0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. 
(2,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,0); 

\draw[blue,name path=B,save path=\pathB] 
(0,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. 
(2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,1);

\path[name intersections={of=A and B}]
(intersection-1) coordinate (M)
(intersection-2) coordinate (N)
(current bounding box.north) coordinate (P)
(current bounding box.south) coordinate (Q);
\path (M); \pgfgetlastxy{\Mx}{\My} 
\path (N); \pgfgetlastxy{\Nx}{\Ny}
\path (P); \pgfgetlastxy{\Px}{\Py}
\path (Q); \pgfgetlastxy{\Qx}{\Qy}

\begin{scope}
\fill[white] (\Mx,\Qy) rectangle (\Nx,\Py);
\clip (\Mx,\Qy) rectangle (\Nx,\Py);
\draw[red,dashed,use path=\pathA];
\draw[blue,use path=\pathB]; 
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A shorter code is as follows.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,name path=A,save path=\pathA]  
(0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. 
(2,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,0); 

\draw[blue,name path=B,save path=\pathB] 
(0,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. 
(2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,1);

\path[name intersections={of=A and B}]
(intersection-1) coordinate (M)
(intersection-2) coordinate (N)
(current bounding box.north) coordinate (P)
(current bounding box.south) coordinate (Q);

\begin{scope}
\fill[white] (M|-Q) rectangle (N|-P);
\clip (M|-Q) rectangle (N|-P);
\draw[red,dashed,use path=\pathA];
\draw[blue,use path=\pathB]; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I cannot compile your code. My program does not recognize the "use path" key. Did you miss a package here?

Comment: @VictorFluxRadkow Updating your Miktex, or using TexLive 2019 pls

Comment: I'm using Texmaker 5.0.3, which is the latest version.

Comment: @VictorFluxRadkow It seems that you are very new to LaTeX and TikZ. TexMaker is just your cloths, meanwhile Miktex (or TexLive) is your body. So you need to update MikTex - your body: type Miktex console on the command line, then update with Administration previllege

Comment: Yes I am new to Latex, but it was a bit hurtful to point it out. Thank you, now it works! Thank you very much for your  answer and help!

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.0 of the [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) package introduces routines to split curves at intersection points and then render their components with different styles.  Using that, your diagram can be coded as follows.  Note that to get the crossing effect I insert actual gaps in the paths rather than using the wipe-out technique.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500081/86}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, spath3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [spath/save=A] (0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,1).. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,0) ; 
\path [spath/save=B] (0,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (2,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (4,1) ;

\tikzset{
  spath/split at intersections={A}{B},
  spath/spot weld=B,
  spath/insert gaps after components={A}{5pt}{1,2},
  spath/get components of=A\Acpts
}

\draw[blue, ultra thick, spath/restore=B];

\tikzset{
  every A component/.style={ultra thick, red, draw},
  A component 2/.style={dashed},
  spath/render components=A,
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Braid with dashed component.]